# How to change the width of custom pages in GAE's Admin Console?

Tags: java, python, html, css, google-app-engine

I have added a custom page to my GAE app. Everything works fine except that the Admin Console limits the size of the custom page content to 73 em. This is done by the CSS class **g-doc-1024**.

```
.g-doc-1024 {
  width: 73.074em;
}
```

**Is there a way to change the CSS on this page so that we can benefit from big monitors when using the Admin Console?** Is this something that can be achieved (1) through configuration or (2) from the iframe of the custom page?

We want to use custom pages so that everything stays in one place. But the CSS of the Admin Console stops people from using our custom pages.

*Updates:*

- Looks like there is a feature request about this in [issue 6629](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6627). Please star the issue!
- As a workaround, a custom [chrome extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/) could be used to fix the CSS of the Admin Console.